# In Riot JS application the update hook gets called but the changes are not reflected in the DOM . What can be the reason?

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I am using a navigation tab in a tag. On clicking the tab, a variable 'activeNav' is updated with the value of the clicked tab.

On basis of 'activeNav' other tags are rendered conditionally.
In one of these conditionally rendered tag if the data is too huge the following problem occurs

- On changing the tab the value of 'activeNav' is set. This value is received in the update hook too. But the DOM takes about 5-6 seconds to receive this change. 
  Also this is seen in the browser's console - [Violation] 'click' handler took 9523ms

Note: The huge data is in child tag and the problem is occurring in the parent tag.

Has anyone faced such issue?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There was a loop running on changing the tabs due to which DOM showed delay in displaying the updates.